# Eclipse error: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" not found in PATH. How to remove this error? i dont need this provider

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I get this error when compiling in Linux:

> Project Properties, C++ Preprocessor Include.../Providers, [CDT Cross
> GCC Built-in Compiler Settings] options Program
> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" not found in PATH

Compilation goes fine, but i want to resolve this error. When i go to Preprocessor Included Paths, Macros, etc. under Providers tabs i see that provider, but is imposible to remove it. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: The error message names *"[CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings]"*, not ...MinGW. Do you mean that you cannot switch off the check mark at "CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings"? For what target do you build your program? What tool chain is selected in "Tool Chain Editor"? Please [edit] your question to provide requested information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In Tool Chain Editor i switched to Linux GCC then back to Cross Gcc and everything is fine now.